# Removing duplicate codes from if/else and try clause

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-duplication

Sonar has marked the below-mentioned code as duplicate, and I am not able to understand how to refactor the code as the fragments of the code exist in the if/else and try clause.

First Method:

```
private void createGenericCar(List<Result> results, GenericCar genericCarNode) {
    if (genericCarNodeId == null || genericCarNodeId.isEmpty()) {
        results.add(new Result.Builder().state(State.ERROR).errorMessage(#########).build());
    } else {
        List<Object> logAttributes = GenericCarDataHelper.getGenericCarLogAttribute(genericCarNodeId);
        var transactionManager = new TransactionManager();
        transactionManager.createTransactionContext();
        try {
            genericCarPersistenceService.validateGenericCarAttributes(genericCarNode);
            NodeNamesInfo names = genericCarDecorator.getNodeNameInfo(genericCarNode);
            transactionManager.startTransaction();
            transactionResults = new ArrayList<>();
            String nodeInternalName = names.getInternalName();
            String parentPartTypeInternalName = Constants.Types.NODE_yyy_INTERNAL_NAME;
            String parent = genericCarNode.getParent();
            var parentInternalName = "";
            if (parent.equals(Constants.Classification.GENERIC_CAR_NODE_GUID)) {
                parentInternalName = Constants.Classification.GENERIC_CAR_FIRST_NODE;
                parentPartTypeInternalName = Constants.Types.ROOT_INTERNAL_NAME;
            } else if (!parent.isEmpty()) {
                parentInternalName = Constants.Classification.GENERIC_CAR_INTERNAL_NAME_PREFIX + parent;
            }
            $
            $
            $(not duplicated code)
            $
            $
            } catch(###) {
        }
    }
}
```

Second method:

```
private void updateGenericCar(List<Result> results, GenericCar genericCarNode) {
    if (genericCarNodeId == null || genericCarNodeId.isEmpty()) {
        results.add(new Result.Builder().state(State.ERROR).errorMessage(#########).build());
    } else {
        List<Object> logAttributes = GenericCarDataHelper.getGenericCarLogAttribute(genericCarNodeId);
        var transactionManager = new TransactionManager();
        transactionManager.createTransactionContext();
        try {
            genericCarPersistenceService.validateGenericCarAttributes(genericCarNode);
            NodeNamesInfo names = genericCarDecorator.getNodeNameInfo(genericCarNode);
            transactionManager.startTransaction();
            transactionResults = new ArrayList<>();
            String partTypeInternalName = Constants.Types.NODE_yyy_INTERNAL_NAME;
            String parent = genericCarNode.getParent();
            String parentInternalName = GenericCarDataHelper.getGenericCarParentInternalName(parent);
            String nodeHierachy = classificationService.getNodeHierarchy(names.getInternalName());
            var updateNodeResult = classificationService.updateNode(names.getInternalName(), names.getDisplayNameEn(), names.getDisplayNameDe(), Collections.emptyMap(), parentInternalName);
            $
            $
            $(not duplicated code)
            $
            $
            } catch(###) {
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Which line is duplicate. I think the same code block is already existing in your file, that's the reason sonar might have marked this whole block as duplicate.

Comment: Sonar is not expecting you to refactor the code, it is complaining that same lines of code is being used in more than one class/method and recommending you to look for opportunities to re-use.

Comment: @Arpit All the above-mentioned lines are duplicated in another method.

Comment: @GopinathRadhakrishnan Yes, and that is where I am stuck as in how to re-use it. I am not so experienced in java, read a few articles but I am not able to figure out how can I remove only this part of duplicate code.

Comment: Yes, so what you should do is create a Utility class, put this method there and call this method from as many places you want. so in this way you will not have duplicate block and sonar wont trouble you.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question @Arpit

Comment: I don't think we can help you unless you show us the code that this is allegedly a duplicate of.  As far as I can see, there is not duplication >within< this code.  The other option is to simply ignore Sonarqube's warning.

Comment: @StephenC I have updated the codes.

Comment: @Rishabh please check, i have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Since the method is duplicate, I would suggest you to either refactor it and create one private method and use it from different places in your class, or if method is being used from multiple classes then I would suggest you to create a Utility class and move the method in Utility class and use it from as many places you want.

This way sonar wont trouble you. Sample code below.

```
   public class MyUtility {
      public static someUniqueCodeBlock() {
        List<Object> logAttributes = GenericCarDataHelper.getGenericCarLogAttribute(genericCarNodeId);
        var transactionManager = new TransactionManager();
        transactionManager.createTransactionContext();
        try {
            genericCarPersistenceService.validateGenericCarAttributes(genericCarNode);
            NodeNamesInfo names = genericCarDecorator.getNodeNameInfo(genericCarNode);
            transactionManager.startTransaction();
            transactionResults = new ArrayList<>();
            String partTypeInternalName = Constants.Types.NODE_yyy_INTERNAL_NAME;
            String parent = genericCarNode.getParent();
            String parentInternalName = GenericCarDataHelper.getGenericCarParentInternalName(parent);
            String nodeHierachy = classificationService.getNodeHierarchy(names.getInternalName());
            var updateNodeResult = classificationService.updateNode(names.getInternalName(), names.getDisplayNameEn(), names.getDisplayNameDe(), Collections.emptyMap(), parentInternalName);
      } catch(###) {
            }
    }
    
    class Caller {
    private void createGenericCar(List<Result> results, GenericCar genericCarNode) {
        if (genericCarNodeId == null || genericCarNodeId.isEmpty()) {
            results.add(new Result.Builder().state(State.ERROR).errorMessage(#########).build());
        } else {
MyUtility.someUniqueCodeBlock();
                $
                $
                $(not duplicated code)
                $
                $
                
        }
    }
      
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Just wondering, is it a good idea to separate the try clause like that?

Comment: no you need to remove catch as well. let me edit.